# how to update multiple tables in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

can anyone tell me whats wrong in this code

```
$sql = "
UPDATE graduation
     , classxii
     , classx
   SET university = '$university'
     , college ='$college'
     , course = '$course'
     , branch = '$branch'
     , year = '$year'
     , school1 = '$school1'
     , board1 = '$board1'
     , percentage1 = '$percentage1'
     , year1 = '$year1'
     , school2 = '$school2'
     , board2 = '$board2'
     , percentage2 = '$percentage2'
     , `year2 = '$year2'
     WHERE graduation.email = '$email'
     , classxii.email = '$email'
     , classx.email = '$email'
";
```

Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' `classxii.email`='rajdeep@gmail.com', `classx.email`='rajdeep@gmail.com''

Comment: You're trying to update multiple tables, correct?

Comment: It isn't a prepared statement.  Use prepared statements and relieve yourself of some potential headaches.

Comment: @jboneca yes, 3 different table

Comment: *"run multiple queries in mysql php"* - what you posted doesn't support that (question title). Update multiple tables ok, but not "multiple queries"; two different animals entirely.

Comment: You're missing some ands

Answer (score 2):

Multiple conditions need to be connected with `AND` or `OR`, not commas.

```
$sql = "UPDATE `graduation`, `classxii`, `classx` SET 
    `university`='$university',`college`='$college',`course`='$course',`branch`='$branch',`year`='$year',
    `school1`='$school1',`board1`='$board1',`percentage1`='$percentage1',`year1`='$year1',
    `school2`='$school2',`board2`='$board2',`percentage2`='$percentage2',`year2`='$year2'
WHERE `graduation`.`email`='$email' AND `classxii`.`email`='$email' AND `classx`.`email`='$email'";
```

Also, the `.` that separates the table name from the column name must not be inside the backticks.

None of your table or column names are reserved words, so you don't need all those noisy backticks at all.

```
$sql = "UPDATE graduation, classxii, classx SET 
    university='$university',college='$college',course='$course',branch='$branch',year='$year',
    school1='$school1',board1='$board1',percentage1='$percentage1',year1='$year1',
    school2='$school2',board2='$board2',percentage2='$percentage2',year2='$year2'
WHERE graduation.email='$email' AND classxii.email='$email' AND classx.email='$email'";
```

Comment: Show this as a prepared statement.  This example is showing how to use as is and enforces bad practices.

Comment: @KraangPrime More work than I want to do for this trivial question. Feel free to post your own answer.

Comment: Fair enough.  I got blasted at for not providing a revised version inclusive of swapping the code from sql injection friendly to prepared statements on a different question which contained sql code.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' `classxii`.`email`='rajdeep@gmail.com', `classx`.`email`='rajdeep@gmail.com'' at line 5

Comment: Make sure you have all the quotes and backticks correct. Although you don't really need any of the backticks, since none of your names are reserved words.

Comment: @Barmar at this point in time, this could be due to a quote being introduced `right syntax to use near '` (the quote suggests it). Or, they didn't copy your code "exactly" as shown. Could also be a mix of both.